# ScrollMagic and full page background

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollmagic

I need to be able to add a gradient and stretch throughout the entire page. However, for some reason, the gradient keeps repeating on each section. I have tried having `min-height: 100%`, removing `height:100%`, adding `height:auto`; adding the gradient in the wrapper or body instead of `html`. However, doing these things brings the layout of the containers and body for me. What is the best way around this? **I need to keep the `height: 100%`**

```
    html {
      color: #222;
      font-size: 1em;
      line-height: 1.4;
      height: 100%;
      background: linear-gradient(tomato, crimson);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      //background-size: cover;
      //background-size: auto, cover;
      //background-position: top left, center;
      //b
}
```

https://codepen.io/ke1993/pen/OXqYYm

Answer (score 0):

change you html css to:

```
html {
  color: #222;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.4;
  background: linear-gradient(tomato, crimson);
}
```

This will remove the height and make it work automatically to the page size. The gradient will then blend automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your whole code into a wrapper, just as I have done in your *Codepen*, the wrapper has class `page-wrapper` and assign the `gradient` to that class.

Here I have made changes in your [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/vivekkupadhyay/pen/vKPqgg)

```
.page-wrapper {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(tomato, crimson);
  background: linear-gradient(tomato, crimson);
}
```

Comment: It's still not working :( this is a better example. https://codepen.io/ke1993/pen/LkaKWN

Comment: @iyuyguyg but in your better example, gradient is keep repeating itself in each section.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Css to this, you can keep   height:100%;

```
 html {
  color: #222;
  font-size: 1em;
  line-height: 1.4;
  height:100%;
}

html, body {
  //height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(tomato, crimson);

}
```

https://codepen.io/mhadaily/pen/qNvzmb